# Unable to drop Serverless database in Synapse Studio

Tags: database, azure-synapse, drop

From Synapse Studio, I created the database [tbfb_Test_ExtermalTables] in the serverless Built-in SQL pool, but can't delete/drop it now. There is no connection to this database. Monitor > SQL Request > all are either Complete or Failed.

```
drop DATABASE [tbfb_Test_extermalTables]
5:06:48 PM
Started executing query at Line 6
Cannot drop database "tbfb_Test_extermalTables" because it is currently in use.
Total execution time: 00:00:20.764


use master;
go
ALTER DATABASE [tbfb_Test_ExtermalTables] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
Go
5:10:04 PM
Started executing query at Line 5
Changed database context to 'master'.

SINGLE_USER is not supported for ALTER DATABASE.
Total execution time: 00:00:00.634
```

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Doesn't look like you can set to single user and drop like you can with SQL Server.